# Google Analytics is taking too long to update despite events being below 40K per day

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

We have always had between 200K - 400K events per day reported on GA.
This never caused a problem. Our GA updates took place every few minutes.

Last month our GA started updating slower and slower, sometimes only once a day. (Meaning we would refresh the GA webpage and it would show zero traffic till about 5PM for that day).

We then read articles and forums online and concluded we had too many events per day.

Based on this, we have for the past 10 days trimmed our events substantially, down to 40K per day.

For two days GA updated every 2-5 minutes, and now again we are seeing it update between once and twice a day (very frustrating).

What are the possible reasons for this?

---

Further information:

- We are not using Tag Manager, but if it solves this issue, we will switch right away.
- The only warning I have right now is this: `Missing Campaign Parameters
  Property XYZ is receiving hits with missing campaign parameters.`
- A previous resolved warning was this: `Too Many Event Labels
  (other) entry present in reports for property XYZ.`

Comment: When you talk about your data being updated, do you mean the previous day's data showing up in your standard reports? Because if you are talking about the current day's data, then you should consider yourself fortunate that you can get it in under 5 minutes. Normal processing time is usually 24 hours.

Comment: Earlier we were getting it under 5 minutes, now it updates twice a day. or once a day.

Comment: I would consider that normal. You shouldn't expect the data to be available so quickly. From my experience, even if the current day's data does appear in your standard reports, it's not always a good idea to use it until the next day after full processing.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it, but I'm surprised that earlier we would refresh the page, and our data would very often be updated, and you're saying that's irregular.

I guess we've been spoilt in the time we were lucky.

Comment: Are you using GA Premium? Even Premium users need to wait at least 4 hours.

Comment: No not at all, we're on unpaid free GA.